# Docker Volume not saving

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, hsqldb

In my Dockerfile, I have this line to create a data volume

```
VOLUME /Infrared360SA
```

I see that this volume was created by running the following:

```
zack@zack-Inspiron-5748:~/Docker$ sudo docker volume inspect Infrared360SA
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/Infrared360SA/_data",
        "Name": "Infrared360SA",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

When I run my application via `docker run` however, I'm not seeing data persist underneath that directory.  The application I'm trying to run is an embedded **tomcat** web app that uses an **hsql** database.  I can run this web application no problem from the command line via a **java** startup command and see database changes persist to **hsql** but when I run the same exact command in the Docker container data is not persisting.

How do I get data to persist inside the volume I defined?

Comment: Can you show us the docker run command please ?

Comment: My run command is `sudo docker run avada/ir360sa-5.8.2.0`. `avada/ir360sa-5.8.2.0` is the image I built on my machine.

Comment: Does you hsql url point to the mounted volume, e.g. `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Infrared360SA/my.db` ?

Comment: @DavidSiro Good question!  Right now my `hsqldb` connection url points to "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/ir360".  Do I have to use a different url form inside of Docker?

Comment: Well, that depends. You're using _server mode_  for hsql (your url point to the hsql server on locahost) now. That means your have to run the hsql server somewhere and it should be accessible from your docker image. If you switch to standalone mode (as in my comment), the hsql db would run within the JVM of your app and would use the mounted volume for its storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correclty created your docker volume with `docker volume create`.

You should bind your docker-volume with your dockerfile volume in the docker run command.
This way :

```
sudo docker run -v Infrared360SA:/Infrared360SA avada/ir360sa-5.8.2.0 avada/ir360sa-5.8.2.0
```

Comment: If I already define a volume inside of my Dockerfile, why would I have to bind it like that?  Wouldn't it just use the Volume I defined in my Dockerfile?

Comment: In your dockerfile, you just declare that you will have a directory /Infrared360SA. It does not have to be mount from a docker-volume, it can also be mount from an other container (`--volumes-from other-container`) or directly a directory in your machine `-v localPath:/containerPath`. In fact, the volume instruction in your Dockerfile is purely declarative in your case. You could skip it. The following example is working : `docker volume create toto && docker run -it -v toto:/tata ubuntu`. the /tata folder in my container is bound to the docker volume toto.

Comment: That's not true. `VOLUME` alone creates the the directory on the host system and mounts it to the container. This can be even seen from the OP's docker inspect result (`"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/Infrared360SA/_data"`).

Comment: This answer is completely accurate, you can't create named volumes on the docker host with the image definition. This would be a security vulnerability where an update to a now malicious container mounts a volume name commonly used for secrets and sends them over the network. It would also create constant collisions from images using the same name. I personally recommend against volumes defined in the Dockerfile, there's no benefit, pass the name in the docket-compose or on docker run.